# openstack-octavia: failed to create amphora disk-image

Tags: openstack

I configure openstack victoria multi-node on CentOS8. When I create amphora-disk-image (option -r rootpassword), I have an issue:

```
[root@controller ~(keystone)]# dnf --enablerepo=centos-openstack-victoria,powertools,epel -y install openstack-octavia-diskimage-create debootstrap
[root@controller ~(keystone)]# sudo octavia-diskimage-create.sh -r rootpassword
```

And **exec_sudo failed**

```
2021-05-08 17:00:22.057 | INFO diskimage_builder.block_device.blockdevice [-] Getting value for [image-path]
2021-05-08 17:00:22.497 | INFO diskimage_builder.block_device.level3.mount [-] Called for [mount_mkfs_root]
2021-05-08 17:00:22.497 | INFO diskimage_builder.block_device.utils [-] Calling [sudo sync]
2021-05-08 17:00:22.522 | INFO diskimage_builder.block_device.utils [-] Calling [sudo fstrim --verbose /tmp/dib_build.jx0MDPok/mnt/]
2021-05-08 17:00:22.554 | INFO diskimage_builder.block_device.utils [-] Calling [sudo umount /tmp/dib_build.jx0MDPok/mnt/]
2021-05-08 17:00:22.721 | INFO diskimage_builder.block_device.utils [-] Calling [sudo kpartx -d /dev/loop0]
2021-05-08 17:00:22.751 | Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-05-08 17:00:22.751 |   File "/bin/dib-block-device", line 10, in <module>
2021-05-08 17:00:22.751 |     sys.exit(main())
2021-05-08 17:00:22.751 |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/diskimage_builder/block_device/cmd.py", line 120, in main
2021-05-08 17:00:22.751 |     return bdc.main()
2021-05-08 17:00:22.751 |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/diskimage_builder/block_device/cmd.py", line 115, in main
2021-05-08 17:00:22.751 |     self.args.func()
2021-05-08 17:00:22.751 |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/diskimage_builder/block_device/cmd.py", line 39, in cmd_umount
2021-05-08 17:00:22.751 |     self.bd.cmd_umount()
2021-05-08 17:00:22.751 |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/diskimage_builder/block_device/blockdevice.py", line 442, in cmd_umount
2021-05-08 17:00:22.751 |     node.umount()
2021-05-08 17:00:22.751 |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/diskimage_builder/block_device/level1/partition.py", line 88, in umount
2021-05-08 17:00:22.751 |     self.partitioning.umount()
2021-05-08 17:00:22.751 |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/diskimage_builder/block_device/level1/partitioning.py", line 228, in umount
2021-05-08 17:00:22.751 |     self.state['blockdev'][self.base]['device']])
2021-05-08 17:00:22.751 |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/diskimage_builder/block_device/utils.py", line 143, in exec_sudo
2021-05-08 17:00:22.751 |     raise e
2021-05-08 17:00:22.751 | diskimage_builder.block_device.exception.BlockDeviceSetupException: exec_sudo failed
2021-05-08 17:00:23.208 | INFO diskimage_builder.block_device.level3.mount [-] Called for [mount_mkfs_root]
2021-05-08 17:00:23.208 | INFO diskimage_builder.block_device.utils [-] Calling [sudo sync]
2021-05-08 17:00:23.233 | INFO diskimage_builder.block_device.utils [-] Calling [sudo fstrim --verbose /tmp/dib_build.jx0MDPok/mnt/]
2021-05-08 17:00:23.255 | Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-05-08 17:00:23.255 |   File "/bin/dib-block-device", line 10, in <module>
2021-05-08 17:00:23.256 |     sys.exit(main())
2021-05-08 17:00:23.256 |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/diskimage_builder/block_device/cmd.py", line 120, in main
2021-05-08 17:00:23.256 |     return bdc.main()
2021-05-08 17:00:23.256 |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/diskimage_builder/block_device/cmd.py", line 115, in main
2021-05-08 17:00:23.256 |     self.args.func()
2021-05-08 17:00:23.256 |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/diskimage_builder/block_device/cmd.py", line 39, in cmd_umount
2021-05-08 17:00:23.256 |     self.bd.cmd_umount()
2021-05-08 17:00:23.256 |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/diskimage_builder/block_device/blockdevice.py", line 442, in cmd_umount
2021-05-08 17:00:23.256 |     node.umount()
2021-05-08 17:00:23.256 |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/diskimage_builder/block_device/level3/mount.py", line 111, in umount
2021-05-08 17:00:23.256 |     self.state['mount'][self.mount_point]['path']])
2021-05-08 17:00:23.256 |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/diskimage_builder/block_device/utils.py", line 143, in exec_sudo
2021-05-08 17:00:23.256 |     raise e
2021-05-08 17:00:23.256 | diskimage_builder.block_device.exception.BlockDeviceSetupException: exec_sudo failed
```

**The reason I create amphora-disk-image with root password because I guess firewalld of amphora block port 9443. So that, octavia-api can't connect to amphora-instance to create --vip-subnet-id loadbalancer. My other post of this issue here if you can check it out:  [Openstack Octavia Error: WARNING octavia.amphorae.drivers.haproxy.rest_api_driver [-] Could not connect to instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67406980/openstack-octavia-error-warning-octavia-amphorae-drivers-haproxy-rest-api-drive?noredirect=1#comment119149656_67406980)

**Best regards!**

Comment: I would check the failing code line. Perhaps a command executed by exec_sudo is not at the expected path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully created amphora-image with my option. I don't know what cause that issue, I just boot all openstack-multi node and let octavia-disk-image-create running until done. Regards !